# Saving model artifacts with Kubeflow without Pipeline

Tags: python, kubeflow, mlflow

I am using mlflow as of now in my jupyterhub environment for model tracking and I feel its easy to keep track of artifacts in mlflow simply by calling the run like:

```
with mlflow.start_run():
    lr = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, random_state=42)
    lr.fit(train_x, train_y)

    predicted_qualities = lr.predict(test_x)

    (rmse, mae, r2) = eval_metrics(test_y, predicted_qualities)

    mlflow.log_param("alpha", alpha)
    mlflow.log_param("l1_ratio", l1_ratio)
    mlflow.log_metric("rmse", rmse)
    mlflow.log_metric("r2", r2)
    mlflow.log_metric("mae", mae)

    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model")
```

I am moving to Kubeflow now and not sure if I can do the same thing here without creating a pipleline. What I could find is:

```
client.run_pipleline(exp.id, ....)
```

Is there any way I can keep track of experiments like mlflow in Kubeflow?

Answer (score 0):

With Kubeflow 0.6 you can do that (at least in Juypter Notebooks, don't think it's integrated with Kubeflow Pipelines yet).

There's a sample here: https://github.com/kubeflow/metadata/blob/master/sdk/python/sample/demo.ipynb

Copying some snippets here if the link dies in future:

```
from kubeflow.metadata import metadata

# Create a workspace and use similar APIs to create execution
ws1 = metadata.Workspace(
    # Connect to metadata-service in namesapce kubeflow in k8s cluster.
    backend_url_prefix="metadata-service.kubeflow:8080",
    name="ws1",
    description="a workspace for testing",
    labels={"n1": "v1"})
```

Log a data in a given `exec` with:

```
data_set = exec.log_input(
        metadata.DataSet(
            description="an example data",
            name="mytable-dump",
            owner="owner@my-company.org",
            uri="file://path/to/dataset",
            version="v1.0.0",
            query="SELECT * FROM mytable"))
assert data_set.id
print("data set id is %s" % data_set.id)
```